# Should I add "are" after Women in this sentence? Or adding "are" is redundant?

Tags: comparison, comparative-constructions

***Original sentence:***

*Well-Off White men are 3 times more likely than women to get job Interviews*

***Edited one:***

*Well-Off White men are 3 times more likely than women are to get job Interviews*

---

Adding "are" is redundant?

Comment: Have you checked the general structure of a comparative-construction? Let's check the examples given in the tag wiki: "You're tall as your father." or "This one is better than that one." How many times does the verb to be appear in those constructions?

Comment: @RubioRic I've changed the tag. Is it correct now?

Comment: That's not what I meant. The tag was right. I was just pointing that there is no need for the second "are", as you can see in those examples.

Comment: @RubioRic Is adding "are" acceptable in terms of grammar?

Comment: Both of them work and both are in fairly common usage - with and without the 'are'. You did not ask, but I'll throw these in anyway: I would not capitalize 'Off' in 'Well-Off' though. And we used to always spell numerals up to somewhere around 10, so I might suggest three instead of 3.